# Moment.js - Simplified List of Time Zones

Tags: momentjs

Is there a way to get a simplified list of *currently applicable* time zones using moment.js / moment-timezone?

Per https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/, we can use moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js to limit the data included. And with Webpack (MomentTimezoneDataPlugin), we can limit data to just specific years. But it still includes all time zones, even those that are no longer widely used.

E.g.

```
// webpack.config.js
new MomentTimezoneDataPlugin({
  startYear: currentYear - 2,
  endYear: currentYear + 5,
})

//Code
moment.tz.zonesForCountry("US");
```

Returns the following:

```
America/Adak
America/Anchorage
America/Boise
America/Chicago
America/Denver
America/Detroit
America/Indiana/Indianapolis
America/Indiana/Knox
America/Indiana/Marengo
America/Indiana/Petersburg
America/Indiana/Tell_City
America/Indiana/Vevay
America/Indiana/Vincennes
America/Indiana/Winamac
America/Juneau
America/Kentucky/Louisville
America/Kentucky/Monticello
America/Los_Angeles
America/Menominee
America/Metlakatla
America/New_York
America/Nome
America/North_Dakota/Beulah
America/North_Dakota/Center
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
America/Phoenix
America/Sitka
America/Yakutat
Pacific/Honolulu
```

This is clearly a much longer list of time zones than you would want most users in the US to choose from in a dropdown. But how do we pare this down to what's applicable?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to the multitude-of-time-zones problem is to generate a custom `latest.json` file and use the webpack `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to substitute the curated `latest.json` for the the default moment-timezone version. You should be able to do this with the 10-year data set or any custom year range.

Webpack config:

```js
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /moment-timezone\/data\/packed\/latest\.json/,
      require.resolve("./continental-time-zones.json"),
    ),
```

And `continental-timezones.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2018g",
  "zones": [
    "America/Chicago|LMT CST CDT EST CWT CPT|5O.A 60 50 50 50 50|01212121212121212 [...]",
    "America/Denver|LMT MST MDT MWT MPT|6X.U 70 60 60 60|01212121 [...]",
    "America/Los_Angeles|LMT PST PDT PWT PPT|7Q.W 80 70 70 70|01212134121 [...]",
    "America/New_York|LMT EST EDT EWT EPT|4U.2 50 40 40 40|012121212121212 [...]"
  ],
  "links": [
    "America/Chicago|US/Central",
    "America/Denver|US/Mountain",
    "America/Los_Angeles|US/Pacific",
    "America/New_York|US/Eastern"
  ]
}
```

I currently generate the `continental-timezones.json` file manually by copying the desired data from moment-timezone's `latest.json`, but it could easily be generated with a simple script as part of a build process.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that's part of the challenge. I'm not sure what all of the "actively used" time zones are around the world. For the US, sure. But moment.js has 16 time zones for Brazil, 13 for Australia, 28 for Canada, etc, etc... I have no idea which of them should be included.

Comment: @phil My apologies, I misunderstood your question. You're asking how to determine which time zones are actually used in the real world, not how to limit your site to those commonly-used time zones? That's a very interesting question. I'm not sure there will be a single answer, since definitions of "actively used" will vary widely. For example, is the canonical time zone America/Boise actively used, even though it covers a small, low-density area of the country, and it's identical to the better-known America/Denver?